# Excel Argument Not Optional

Tags: excel, vba

Hey I am creating a form that has multiple buttons that trigger different subroutines. The first code works by for the second code

```
Sub LateReports_Click()
    Dim ThisYear As Interior
    Dim ThisMonth As String

' Create a new workbook for Late Tools in the current year and month folder
ThisYear = Year(Now())
ThisMonth = MonthName(Now())
Workbooks.Add

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="R:\Tool Calibration\" & ThisYear & "\" & ThisMonth & "\Late_Tools_" & Month & ".xls"

End Sub
```

I get a `Argument not optional` compile error. Any Suggestions?

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: @Dportology "Sub LateReports_Click()"

Comment: You've use `Month` instead of `ThisMonth` in the actual filename portion. The error is because the `Month(...)` function expects a date to parse a numerical month from.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
Sub LateReports_Click()
    Dim ThisYear As Integer
    Dim ThisMonth As String

' Create a new workbook for Late Tools in the current year and month folder
ThisYear = Year(Now())
ThisMonth = MonthName(Now())
Workbooks.Add

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="R:\Tool Calibration\" & ThisYear & "\" & ThisMonth & "\Late_Tools_" & ThisMonth & ".xls"

End Sub
```

My guess is that you meant to declare ThisYear as an Integer, not an Interior, and in your ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs line, you refer to ThisMonth as simply Month

Comment: Ha! Completely missed the `as Interior` bit.